# GTK having issue with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gtk

I am new in C++ stuff and visual studio. Somehow I managed to add GTK lib and includes in Additional Include Directory! here is how i added

```
C:\gtk\include\atk-1.0;C:\gtk\include;C:\gtk\include\gdk-pixbuf-2.0;C:\gtk\include\pango-1.0;C:\gtk\include\cairo;C:\gtk\lib\gtk-2.0\include;C:\gtk\lib\glib-2.0\include;C:\gtk\include\glib-2.0;C:\gtk\include\gtk-2.0;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

all files set correctly and no error with linking.

But when I compiling code I got this errors!
here is image!

[image]

This is unrecognized error for me any one know what's the matter!
here is code (this is basic code i get from tutorial over internet)

```
 #include<gtk\gtk.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    GtkWidget* window;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

thanks for help! and your time

Comment: Should the `gtk\gtk.h` be `gtk/gtk.h`?

Comment: nope!  it's not seem issue I checked it!

Comment: This is a linker problem. It doesn't find the .lib files where the functions are defined. You have to add to the libraries path as well.

Comment: The compilation works, those errors are from the linker. My guess is that you need to tell the linker about the new libraries that it needs to use...

Comment: which lib required! i have added reference to all libs and it's folder but doesn't work can you tell me how to proper configure gtk with visual studio 2010 or higher!